# DatePicker function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two `datepicker` function check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/vdLwvmxp/6/)

```
var divContent = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter date" class="dupInput hasDatepicker" id="gl_img_datepicker" readonly="">';

jQuery("#gl_img_datepicker").datepicker();
jQuery("#gl_img_datepicker2").datepicker();

    jQuery('body').on('click', '#gl_img_datepicker_init', function(e) {
        jQuery("#gl_img_datepicker").datepicker('show');
    });
```

but it does not seems to show the calender. I checked this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johniehjelm/hBTyE/) and also read [api](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but I am not able to find the problem.

I am seeing this error in console

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined "`

please help, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the problem is with the class name 'hasDatepicker'. If you remove that class name it will work fine.

`'hasDatepicker'` class name is used internally in the datepicker plugin. So better to avoid that name in your code.

```
<div id="my div ">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter date" class="dupInput" id="gl_img_datepicker" />
    <button id="gl_img_datepicker_init">Date</button>
</div>

<div id="my_new_div ">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter date" class="dupInput" id="gl_img_datepicker2" />
    <button id="gl_img_datepicker_init2">Date</button>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdLwvmxp/17/)

Comment: Thanks... that was really quick answer :)